# subprocess.call in python not waiting for it to finish

Tags: python, subprocess

when I am trying to call a python script from python and store the output in the text file using subprocess.call it is not waiting for the process to complete and when using subprocess.check_call it is showing error " returned non-zero exit status 1".

Python 2.7 - Windows Server 2012

The subprocess is working fine when I running independently.

Here is the code I am trying to execute

```
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
    subprocess.call(["python", "C:\flycoffee\user.py ", '-q 
    ', 'F34D989B207E003CD9DB40BC2AD0CEC5'], stdout = output)
```

or

```
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
    subprocess.check_call(["python", "C:\flycoffee\user.py ", '-q 
    ', 'F34D989B207E003CD9DB40BC2AD0CEC5'], stdout = output)
```

Comment: Why not just import it?

Comment: `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_call` definitey wait for chid process to finish. But there could be issues with your user.py script. I can think of two: (1) Does `user.py` spawn another subprocess itself, and if so does it wait for that subprocess to finish? (2) Does it need to access to raw console I/O? (not sure it's possible in python on Windows -- on unix it would be tty package). Anyway, it might be worth sharing a few details about what `user.py` does.